# Looking for Python code to act as a MODBUS slave

Tags: python, simulator, modbus

Does anyone know of an easy to use Python program that acts as a MODBUS slave?  I need to do some integration testing with a MODBUS master.  Code can be for serial or TCP.

TY,
Fred

Answer (score 4):

Try this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/modbus_tk
Modbus Test Kit provides implementation of slave and master for Modbus TCP and RTU. 
The main goal is to be used as testing tools.